# Вопрос о селекторе CSS :nth-child()

Tags: css3, css

Доброй ночи, господа! Подскажите, пожалуйста, что мне нужно вписать в скобки селектора CSS :nth-child(), чтобы выбрать каждый четвертый элемент? Заранее, спасибо, за ответы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как это ни странно:

```
:nth-child(4n)
```

Если начиная с первого, то:

```
:nth-child(4n+1)
```

Comment: Может я не правильно задал вопрос, но решил его так - :nth-child(3n+1)

Comment: вам виднее, что вы называете каждым четвертым. Но вот те, кто работает "сутки через трое" были бы с вами не согласны =)